# Laravel 4 query builder join DB raw

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, laravel-query-builder

I am using laravel 4 and have sql query like this

```
select a.*, v.* from (select * from application order by id desc)a join vacancy v on a.vacancy_id = v.id group by a.email
```

my problem is how I can write in query builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this. (untested)

```
$subQuery = DB::table('application')->orderBy('id', 'desc');

$result = DB::table(\DB::raw("({$subQuery->toSql()}) as a"))
    ->mergeBindings($subQuery)
    ->selectRaw("a.*, v.*")
    ->join('vacancy as v', 'a.vancancy_id', 'v.id')
    ->groupBy('a.email')
    ->get();
```

Comment: hy chanafdo thanks for your answer but I have quetions from your code what  the meaning **->getQuery()** because i'm try but error in **getQuery()** thanks

Comment: oh i'm sorry ok, but still error **Every derived table must have its own alias**